# Drupal: Sharing content across Multisite

Tags: drupal

I have 2 websites with similar content types.

Let's say an event-content type with some cck fields in it.

site1: events ( title, body, image )
site2: events ( title, body, image, onsite1)

by the extra field at site2-events i want to give the possibility to the user to post his event on the ( main ) site1.

Site1 and site2 are both on 1 database, although tables from site2 are prefixed.

How can i add content made from site2 to site1?
( Is there an easy way to do this without resorting to sql? I am using the nodeapi at this time to do some extra when an event is submitted. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you're already using hook_nodeapi it seems like you could just do:

```
if ($op == 'insert' && (see if checkbox is checked here))
```

...then [switch to the other site's database](http://drupal.org/node/18429), do a node_save, and switch back to the current site's database to let Drupal finish its business.

Comment: Both websites are in 1 database because some tables (taxonomy) are shared. The tables of site2 are prefixed. , so the switch of database using db_set_active() won't work. Unless i've missed something. I'll have a look at your link asap.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use db_set_active() as Mike-Crittenden describes even if it is within same database, as both $db_url and $db_prefix can be arrays, instead of single strings.

This way you can have the same db_url for both 'default' and 'alternative' db, but use different prefixes to switch between databasees using db_set_active('alternative') and db_set_active() to return to default.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people use Feed API / [Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) for this. You can filter by taxonomy terms, content type, whatever you need so that you don't have to import everything from the primary site. Great tool.